# Пакетное создание папок

Tags: файловая-система, командная-строка

Есть такой батник, создает 100 папок с именами от 1 до 100
Подскажите как сделать чтобы названия созданных папок начинались не с "1" а с "525" например
Спасибо

chcp 1251
set papka=0
:1
set /A papka=papka+1
md %papka%
if not %papka%==100 goto 1

Comment: Что мешает вам поменять стартовую цифру с ноля на 525-1 = 524 и поменять конечное условие?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не совсем понимаю, как это сделать

Comment: Вместо нуля вбить другое число. И вместо 100 вбить другое число. Всё.

Comment: Спасибо получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> создает 100 папок с именами ... с "525" например

```
FOR /L %x IN (525, 1, 624) DO md %x
```